# Theorem 19.4 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Does the converse also hold?

Tags: general-topology

Let $J$ be an arbitrary (non-empty) index set, and let $\left\{ X_\alpha \right\}_{\alpha \in J}$ be an indexed family (or collection) of topological spaces, and let $\Pi_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ denote their Cartesian product.

Then here's Theorem 19.4 in the book *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> If each space $X_\alpha$ is a Hausdorff space, then $\Pi_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is a Hausdorff space in both the box and product topologies.

So far so good!

Now my question is, does the converse also hold? That is, if $\Pi_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is a Hausdorff space in either the box or the product topologies, then does it follow that each space $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff also?

Of course, if $\Pi_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff in the product topology, then it is Hausdorff in the box topology also.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the converse is true. If $X=\prod X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff in the box topology, then every factor $X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff, provided that no factor is empty. To prove this, take two distinct points $x_\beta,y_\beta$ in $X_\beta$, and choose $x_\alpha=y_\alpha\in X_\alpha$ for any $\alpha\ne\beta$. Now consider the points $x=(x_\alpha)_\alpha$ and $y=(y_\alpha)_\alpha$ in $X$. By Hausdorffness there exist disjoint open boxes around $x$ and $y$. Can you show that their projections to $X_\beta$ are disjoint as well?

One may also show that every factor is homeomorphic to a subspace of $X$, implying at once that if the box product is $T_0$ ($T_1$, Hausdorff, (completely) regular), then the factor is also $T_0$ ($T_1$, Hausdorff, (completely) regular).

Comment: What about the product topology case? I think you can reduce it to the case of a finite product, where it agrees with the box topology case, so it should also be true, but I haven't checked the details...

Comment: @StefanHamcke thank you so much. Yes, I can verify that. So nice of you!!

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud If $\Pi_{\alpha \in J} X_\alpha$ is Hausdorff in the product topology, then it is also Hausdorff in the box topology as the latter is finer than the former, and Stefan's proof holds.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud Well said, thanks :)